# I want to deploy different ingresses with the same hostname, but an error occurs

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, kubernetes-ingress

※ I apologize for my poor English.

### What I want to do

We want to secure our services through OAuth2-proxy Google authentication in a kubernetes environment. To do so, I deploy two Ingress with the same hostname. The controller is nginx-controller.

The following site is a reference, and after much research, this architecture seems to be the most common.

> https://oak-tree.tech/blog/k8s-nginx-oauth2-gitlab

### ERROR

error message

> 1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"test", Name:"internal-ingress", UID:"96bd61e0-5e0d-4e2d-9941-aeb55cb71958", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"597455", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'Rejected' All hosts are taken by other resources

I am aware that this means that there are duplicate hostnames.

### dealing with

The hostname change resulted in the IPs of the two ingresses being firmly assigned to the same IP address. However, duplicate 80 Port number.

[kubectl get ing -A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJtzy.png)

The port number may be duplicated, so that even if port 80 is used for access, it is rewritten to port 31000.

http://host.kubernetes.external.org:80/
↓
http://host.kubernetes.external.org:31000/

There are no errors in the log...

Is there anything I can do to make this program work?

### Program

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "http://host.kubernetes.external.org/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "http://host.kubernetes.external.org/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"

    # These next four lines are only necessary if you're using cert-manager to generate TLS certificates
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "1024m"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "1024m"
    # cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"

  name: external-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: host.kubernetes.external.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wordpress-test
            port:
              number: 30000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /oauth2
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"

    # These next three lines are only necessary if you're using cert-manager to generate TLS certificates
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "1024m"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "1024m"

  name: internal-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: host.kubernetes.external.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /oauth2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: oauth2-proxy
            port:
              number: 4180
```